# Use macOS "open" command from XCode shell breakpoint

Tags: xcode, shell, debugging, ios-simulator, breakpoints

I need to copy a file into the documents directory of an iOS simulator. It's very annoying to copy paste the long transient path into either the command prompt or "Go to folder" in finder.

To try to automate this, I have a breakpoint after this line of code:

```
let documentsDirectory = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String)
```

The breakpoint is an advanced breakpoint:

[image: An XCode Advanced Breakpoint containting a call to "open %documentsDirectory%"]

But when XCode tries to execute the breakpoint it cannot find the directory/file. In the XCode console output:

`The file /"/Users/bennyty/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/574CAFDE-25C1-44EA-8571-DCD4C2EFBBA1/data/Containers/Data/Application/0805C107-82B9-4C97-A713-6E14AE2C8481/Documents" does not exist.`

Even though `open "/Users/bennyty/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/574CAFDE-25C1-44EA-8571-DCD4C2EFBBA1/data/Containers/Data/Application/0805C107-82B9-4C97-A713-6E14AE2C8481/Documents"` on the command line causes Finder to open correctly.

Also no luck using a shell script that just contains `open $1`